# How to run a firebase sample

Tags: github, intellij-idea, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have cloned a firebase sample from here

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js

I want to run this sample, I have tried with itellij and gitbash but it doe not run

Comment: What is the problem? Did you read the README files in repository?

Comment: well I read the read me , it says nothing of how to run the project

Comment: It is a collection of 4 examples: auth, database, messaging and storage. For example, if you want to run `quickstart-js/messaging` example, [this readme] (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging#firebase-cloud-messaging-quickstart) explains everything you need to run it (e.g. install node.js framework, install firebase CLI from npm, configure the project on Firebase console, etc.). So assuming that you've read it, I've asked you what was your problem in the procedure in order to clarify.

Answer (score 17):

**Messaging example**

1. Install the Node.JS framework ([here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) the link to download for your system). I show you how to do it with Linux but the procedure should be the same.
2. Using command-line install **firebase CLI** using the command: `npm install -g firebase-tools` (may need `sudo` if it fails).
3. Type `firebase login`. This will open your browser and let you login to your Google account.
4. Download the repository with `git clone https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js.git`
5. Enter repo directory `cd quickstart-js`
6. Go to Firebase console [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and then `Create new project`
7. In the dashboard of your project click on `Add Firebase to your web application` and copy the javascript code that is prompted to you.
8. Open `index.html` in `messaging` folder and at line 83 paste the code copied from dashboard.
9. Type command `firebase init` in `messaging` folder and then answer the questions that will be asked you:

   ```
   What Firebase CLI features do you want to setup for this folder?
   --> Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites

   What file should be used for Database Rules?
   --> Blank, it is not relevant for this example.

   What do you want to use as your public directory? (public)
   --> .

   Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?
   --> y

   File ./index.html already exists. Overwrite?
   --> N
   ```
10. Type command `firebase serve -p 8081` (or any other free port you have)
11. Go to http://localhost:8081/index.html
12. Click `Request permission` (the registration token will appear if the operation succeed)
13. In another tab go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging, select your project and save the server key (the long one)
14. Type

    ```
    curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=YOUR-SERVER-KEY" -H "Content-Type:   
    application/json" -d '{
      "notification": {
         "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
         "body": "5 to 1",
         "icon": "firebase-icon.png",
         "click_action": "http://localhost:8081"
       },
       "to": "YOUR-IID-TOKEN"
    }' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    ```

    replacing `YOUR-SERVER-KEY` with the copied server key and `YOUR-IID-TOKEN` with the string appeared [here](http://localhost:8081/index.html) after clicking on `Request permission`. If everything is done correctly a notification will appear in the [local page](http://localhost:8081/index.html) in this form

    ```
    Received message:
    {
      "from": "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "collapse_key": "do_not_collapse",
      "notification": {
        "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
        "body": "5 to 1",
        "icon": "firebase-icon.png",
        "click_action": "http://localhost:8081"
      }
    }
    ```

**Database example**

You don't need to run `firebase init` because the `firebase.json` file is already present and configured in the repository.
But if you want to use it you have to:

1. Paste you credentials (same of the previous step 7) in the `head` section of `index.html` page.
2. Go to firebase dashboard --> your project --> Authentication --> Authentication Method, and choose the method you want (email/password, google, etc.)
3. In `quickstart-js/database` folder type command `firebase serve` and the application will be loaded to [this page](http://localhost:5000).
4. Go to that page and click on `Sign in with Google`, type your credential, and enjoy it! :-)

**Auth example**

You don't need to run `firebase init` because the `firebase.json` file is already present and configured in the repository.
To use it (I've not tried it) with facebook for example you should:

1. Paste your credentials in `facebook-credentials.html` in `head` section
2. In the `script` section at the end of that page paste `<YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID>`
3. Type in folder `quickstart-js/auth` the command `firebase serve` and the application will be loaded to [this page](http://localhost:5000).
4. Go to [localhost:5000](http://localhost:5000) and click on `Facebook Login using OAuth Credentials (via Facebook Login Button)` to login.

If you want to use other methods you'll have to modify the corresponding file in the same way (`facebook-popup.html`, `facebook-redirect`, etc.)

Feel free to ask if it is not clear.

Comment: thank you for the answer ,I need some clarity on step 9 on what to answer (I selected hosting so got the hosting page open up),can you show me how to run auth and databse.

Comment: I tried to do the same with the database sample , after giving firebase init command it asks ,what file should be used for databse rules , what should I specify here?

Comment: I want to specifically run the auth sample with email password login method , I have selected email password login from the sign in list

Comment: I've updated step 9. For database and auth example you don't need to do `firebase init` because the `firebase.json` file is already present and configured. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: This is a great answer, and you've clearly spent a lot of time writing it. Unfortunately, this is not a great question and is likely to get closed. As you become more familiar with SO you'll probably realise that you should save your effort for great questions. If you're unsure what a great question is, read [ask], and if you want to know what makes a great answer, read this: [answer].

Comment: @EngineerDollery thank you for your advice, I decided to write this long answer to help people to start working with Firebase services that it is not very immediate to be used the first time. I don't think that I've spent my time in vain. I accept your remark and I'll try to make a better contribution to this community.

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed example..but I am stuck at point 14 where to type this code :
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=YOUR-SERVER-KEY" -H "Content-Type:   
application/json" -d '{
  "notification": {
     "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
     "body": "5 to 1",
     "icon": "firebase-icon.png",
     "click_action": "http://localhost:8081"
   },
   "to": "YOUR-IID-TOKEN"
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

Comment: Well, for the **Database Quickstart**, it works but not data has been added to the database after creating a 'blog post' (as this is a blog app sample). I tried to deploy to the cloud project (after enabling the **Database** section) and try out the app's functionality again, no data has been added either. When I check the console's Database section, it says **"+Add Collection"** and everything is empty. What should I do?

Comment: Ok guys, found the answer here: Make sure the `read` and `write` permissions of these two files: `firestore.rules` and `database.rules.json` are set to `true` (for **Test Mode** only, not for production). When you run the `firebase deploy`, it works on the web as well. Thanks all!